# Mongodb aggregate on filter like subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

First of all, sorry for my poor English.

If we have below documents in MongoDB,

**Test data**

```
{id:1, filter:{f1:'v1-1', f2:'v2-1', f3:['v3-1', 'v3-3']}}
{id:2, filter:{f1:'v1-1', f2:'v2-2', f3:['v3-2', 'v3-3']}}
{id:3, filter:{f1:'v1-1', f2:'v2-2', f3:['v3-1', 'v3-3']}}
```

**Prepare the collection**

```
db.test.drop()
db.test.insert({id:1, filter:{f1:'v1-1', f2:'v2-1', f3:['v3-1', 'v3-3']}})
db.test.insert({id:2, filter:{f1:'v1-1', f2:'v2-2', f3:['v3-2', 'v3-3']}})
db.test.insert({id:3, filter:{f1:'v1-1', f2:'v2-2', f3:['v3-1', 'v3-3']}})
```

You can consider the filter field as filter function that used on many shopping sites, for example, they will tell you how many LED TVs and how many LCD TVs on the site.

I want to use MongoDB to calculate how many documents with each filter option (include every item in the array field), the expected result is as below.

**Expected result**

```
[
    {
       _id : { key: 'f1', value: 'v1-1' }, count: 3
    },
    {
       _id : { key: 'f2', value: 'v2-1' }, count: 1
    },
    {
       _id : { key: 'f2', value: 'v2-2' }, count: 2
    },
    {
       _id : { key: 'f3', value: 'v3-1' }, count: 2
    },
    {
       _id : { key: 'f3', value: 'v3-2' }, count: 1
    },
    {
       _id : { key: 'f3', value: 'v3-3' }, count: 3
    }
]
```

It's easy to get the result by using map/reduce,

**Map/Reduce solution**

```
map = function () { 
    for (k in this.filter) { 
        if (this.filter[k] instanceof Array) {
            for (j in this.filter[k]) {
                emit( { key: k, value: this.filter[k][j]}, 1 ); 
            }
        } else {
            emit( { key: k, value: this.filter[k]}, 1 ); 
        }
    } 
}

reduce = function (k, values) { 
    result = 0;  
    values.forEach( function(v) { result += v; } ); 
    return result; 
}

db.test.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out:{inline:1}})
```

But as the performance problem with map/reduce, it can't be used for real time query. and the result set may be changed if I add some query conditions, so I can't save the map/reduce result into another collection for real time query.

And I can use aggregate framework to calculate the count for one filter,

**Aggregate solution for only one filter**

```
db.test.aggregate(
{$project: {"filter.f2":1, "_id":0}},
{$group:   {"_id": {"key": {$ifNull: [null, "f2"]}, "value":"$filter.f2"}, "count" : {$sum: 1}}}
)

[
    {
        "_id" : { "key" : "f2", "value" : "v2-2" }, "count" : 2
    },
    {
        "_id" : { "key" : "f2", "value" : "v2-1" }, "count" : 1
    }
]
```

But I don't know how to do it for all filter options. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your data structure to something like this, note that all the values are arrays, even the ones with single values:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  filters: [{
    key: 'f1',
    values: ['v1-1']
  },{
    key: 'f2',
    values: ['v2-1']
  },{
    key: 'f3',
    values: ['v3-1', 'v3-3']
  }]
}
{
  _id: 2,
  filters: [{
    key: 'f1',
    values: ['v1-1']
  },{
    key: 'f2',
    values: ['v2-2']
  },{
    key: 'f3',
    values: ['v3-2', 'v3-3']
  }]
}
{
  _id: 3,
  filters: [{
    key: 'f1',
    values: ['v1-1']
  },{
    key: 'f2',
    values: ['v2-2']
  },{
    key: 'f3',
    values: ['v3-1', 'v3-3']
  }]
}
```

You could do an aggregate function something like this:

```
db.test.aggregate({
  $unwind: "$filters"
},{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    key: "$filters.key",
    values: "$filters.values"
  }
},{
  $unwind: "$values"
},{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      $concat: ["$key","|","$values"]
    },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
})
```

You could probably skip the project step if you want, I just put it in there as a nicety. You'll need two unwinds no matter what though.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I'm using mongodb 2.2, so I need to use `_id: { key: "$key", values: "$values" }` in the $group section.